# AppEngine domain can not be added to the Push Allowed Domains

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I will WebMasterTool, it was verify the myAppId.appspot.com.
However, it is an error to add to the GCP Developers Console of Push Allowed Domains.

Error Message: "You do not have access to the following domain: myAppId.appspot.com"

help me!

Comment: it can take some time, even up to a day, for such changes to permeate through...

Comment: Thanks. I've been waiting for about 15h.

Comment: I found a solution!
The Domain to Verify in the Web Master Tool,
 
    https: //myAppId.appspot.com

, was successful!
It's important to the Domain of Verify in "https"!